# Charts are overlapping with old values on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, asp.net, canvas, chart.js, adminlte

i am using Chart Js for showing bar-chart. and it's values refresh on DropDownList's onChange event.
first time it loads correctly. but, on changing value in DropDownList it loads new value without clearing previous data.

now normally it renders new fresh value. while on mouse hover, it shows old value. my chart work fine except when the user select a different option from drop down and the canvas get reloaded with the new data.

i have tried most of the things i knew to fix this issue.but nothing worked for me.
1. chart.destroy
2. chart.clear
3. no-cache meta tag
4. nullify chart's value before loading new one

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `chart.update()` after changing your data.

`chart` is your variable where you say something like `let chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), { ...`

Without code I can't help you more for now.